# installing TFS, JIRA, Subversion

Tags: windows, svn, tfs, windows-server-2008, jira

Any guy can guide me how long it will take to install (if you never did it before):
- TFS
- JIRA
- Subversion

on a VPS server... (windows 2008 R2)?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA is probably an hour to download, install and configure to talk to JIRA. However I'd recommend using FishEye to connect to Subversion, and then JIRA connects easily to FishEye.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer for Subversion.  I would recommend you download and install a project I manage - [Subversion Edge](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/svnedge/).  It is free and open-source and provides an easy to install packaging of everything you need to setup a Subversion server.  It also includes a simple web user interface for ongoing management and configuration of the server.

You should have at least 1GB of RAM on your VPS, but other than that it is as simple as running a Windows installer and then going to your web browser to configure the server.

Finally, have you considered a different approach?  There are cloud providers like [Codesion](http://codesion.com/) that can host these tools in the cloud for you at a fairly inexpensive price.  This takes away all of the administration details like installation, security and backup.